# How to set minimum and maximum characters limitation to EditText in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to set minimum and maximum input value for EditText box. I am creating one simple validation for EditText; it takes A-Z and 0-9 values with minimum 5 and maximum 8 character.

I set the maximum and other validations as follow:

```
 <EditText 
        android:id="@+id/edittextKode_Listing"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textKode_listing"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textKode_listing"
        android:maxLength="8"
        android:inputType="textCapCharacters"
        android:digits="0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTVUWXYZ"
        />
```

but not able to set minimum value requirement. My EditText box is in an alert dialog. I tried the following code to solve the problem:

```
private void openInboxDialog() {

        LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
        // declare dialog view
        final View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.kirim_layout, null);

        final EditText edittextKode = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.edittextKode_Listing);
        final EditText edittextalamat = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.edittextAlamat);
        edittextKode.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                if(edittextKode.getText().toString().length() > 0){
                    if(edittextKode.getText().toString().length() < 5)
                    {
                        edittextKode.setError("Error");
                        Toast.makeText(GPSActivity.this, "Kode listing value not be less than 5", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        edittextKode.requestFocus();

                    }
                }
            }
        });
        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(GPSActivity.this);
        builder.setTitle("Kirim").setView(dialogView)
                .setNeutralButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        gpsCoordinates = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_GPS_Coordinates);
                        kode = edittextKode.getText().toString();
                        alamat = edittextalamat.getText().toString();
                        catatan = edittextcatatan.getText().toString();
                        pengirim = edittextPengirim.getText().toString();
                        if (kode.length() > 0 && alamat.length() > 0
                                && catatan.length() > 0 && pengirim.length() > 0) {
                            message = "Kode listing : " + kode + "\nAlamat : "
                                    + alamat + " \nCatatan : " + catatan + " \n Pengirim : " + pengirim
                                    + "\nKoordinat GPS : "
                                    + gpsCoordinates.getText().toString();
                                sendByGmail();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(
                                    getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Please fill all three fields to send mail",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
        builder.create();
        builder.show();
    }`
```

In this alert dialog, I have two EditText boxes. I want to apply my validation on first EditText. I called the **setOnFocusChangeListener** to check its minimum length on focus change. If the length is less than 5 then requested for focus, but it still types in second EditText box.

Could anyone please help me.

Answer (score 0):

```
InputFilter[] lengthFilter = new InputFilter[1];
lengthFilter[0] = new InputFilter.LengthFilter(9); //Filter to 9 characters
mEditText.setFilters(lengthFilter);
```

This creates a filter to limit the number of characters.

Comment: This limit the max length, not min. Also, is only for API 23+.

Answer (score -1):

There is no direct way to do this, the only way of doing it, as far as I know, is when the edit text loses focus or when the user submits the information you do length check and see if its less than 5 characters, e.g.

```
if (myTextBox.length() < 5)
{
Log.d("APP", "Sorry, you need to enter at least 5 characters";
}
else
{
Log.d("APP", "Input valid");
}
```

Comment: ya i try this you can see this on my code have to edittext when i click on second edittext the cursor will not go to 1st edittext

Comment: Sorry I missed, that, can't see why it wouldn't request the focus on the text box again though, I'm wondering whether the .setError() has something to do with it, it may be worth taking that out and re-test and see if the focus works then

Comment: thanx for your answer i also try .setError() but it still gone to next edittext

Comment: Are you sure ``edittextKode`` is the correct edittext as Android doesn't change focus to another text box without being told to so I don't see why it would jump to the second text box when your on the first

Comment: i check 100 times i dont even know the reason why it goes directly to 2nd textbox :(

Comment: Nothing Happen @Boardy so just change my logic now at first time i make all my other EditText enable false and chect value of my Edittextkode on the onTextChangedEvent if my condition is true i will make other edittext enable true other wise they always enable false... Thanx for your help

Answer (score -2):

You can do something like this way....in this i checked the character length and if it is greater than 5 then the editText loses the focus..and After Touch on that it gets back the Focus..Try this ..i hope this will help you..

```
 edittextKode.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(arg0.length()>5)
            { 
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContect(),"Max.value is 5",1).show();
                  edittextKode.setFocusable(false);
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });

 edittextKode.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1)
      {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             edittextKode.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score -3):

You can try below code inside  listener  :

If condition is not met,

```
edittextKode.setFocus( true) ;
edittextKode.setFocusableInTouchMode( true)  ;
edittextalamat.setFocus( false) ;
edittextalamat.setFocusableInTouchuha( false) ;
edittextKode.requestFocus();
```