# how to set maximum and minimum character of a EditText field?

Tags: android

set maximum and minimum length of EditText field which check its length as the user types and notify the user(like red color EditText line or small popup which don't intrupt typing). I dont know if this coding should be on xml or java file.

take example of username:
xml file

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etusername"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Username"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:maxLength="25"       
    android:digits="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890"/>
```

.java file

```
EditText etUsername=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.etusername);
String username=etUsername.getText().toString();
btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
             //any operation here
        }
```

Comment: Already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14454093/how-to-set-minimum-and-maximum-characters-limitation-to-edittext-in-android)

Comment: @Adithya should i do this coding separate for every EditText field

Comment: Create a filter and apply it to ones you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the minimum requirement you can do something like this:

Using the `.getText().toString().length()` to choose your minimum length

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
private EditText myEditText;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    myEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myEditText);
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    int lenght = 25;
    myEditText.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {new InputFilter.LengthFilter(lenght)});
    button.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    int i = v.getId();
    if (i == R.id.button) {
        if (myEditText.getText().toString().length() < 4) {
            myEditText.setError("4 char minimum!");
        } else {
            myEditText.setError(null);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a TextWatcher to watch the length

```
etUsername.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(final CharSequence s, final int start, final int count, final int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(final CharSequence s, final int start, final int before, final int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(final Editable s) {
          if(s.toString.length > MAX){
              /// Your code here
          }
        }
    });
```

This will allow the user to continue typing into the field but will let you manually control the error state.  Just be aware that if you manually call

```
etUsername.setText("...");
```

it will retrigger the TextWatcher and can lead to infinite looping

Comment: thanks for your help but in your code what do you mean by showError()? it giving me error

Comment: you can just insert any sort of code you need, whether its showing a toast, or setting an error state on the EditText or whatever.  That callback will be called every time the content of the EditText is changed whether by typing or setText(..)